# Magento2 Script for copying Product Title to Image alt

Tags: magento-2.1, image

we use magento 2.1.9ce

Our products are made through an api. And they fill in the ean number at the image alt location.
And unfortunatly they can't change that.

But i would like to have the products title on the img alt.

Can anyone help me with a script that copies the product title to the img alt?

Comment: Can't you just edit the PHTML file to include an alt to the images?

Comment: i would prefer a script, than i don't have to think about it when a theme updates ....

Comment: So this needs to update the product database image alt with the Product Name? How many products? When does this need to happen is it manual like script you want to be able to fire every so often? or on addition of a product? Change of theme like suggested would be simpler. I would look at how the API is adding the products and change that after fixing current products with an import.

Comment: Failing that observer on the product save event to modify the product object accordingly before save?

Comment: i prefer a manually run script (which i could run with a cron).
Which copies the product title to the image alt in the dbase
Now its about 15K products .... but after first run we can add a line that it should start from a specific id ...

Comment: Sorry i went ahead and did it the way i would do it as didnt see this message... Some of the code will be transferable tho just need to loop through all the products really. I do think think my method would be simpler tho.

Comment: @Ronny I have added a new answer that i thinks suits all your needs for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to add another answer and leave my existing answer as feel this one is more what you are after but like both solutions. Below creates a new **cli command** within **Magento** for updating image **alt tags** so you can run on demand or via **cron** like you have requested.

### di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
                <arguments>
                        <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="update_alt" xsi:type="object">Harrigo\ProductUpdateCmd\Console\Command\UpdateAltCommand</item>
                        </argument>
                </arguments>
        </type>
</config>
```

> **etc/di.xml**

This informs Magento about our new **command** and where to find it.

### UpdateAltCommand.php

```
<?php
namespace Harrigo\ProductUpdateCmd\Console\Command;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductManagementInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UpdateAltCommand extends Command
{

    protected $productModel;
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $productManagement;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $registry;
    protected $state;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface,
        Registry $registry,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        State $state
    ) {
        $this->productModel = $productModel;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepositoryInterface;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->state = $state;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('harrigo:updatealt')->setDescription('Updates Image Alt.');
        $this->addArgument('product_id', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Start from Product ID');
        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true, true);
        try {
            $this->state->getAreaCode();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
        }
        if ($input->getArgument('product_id')) {
          $output->writeln('Updating Image Tags from ID: ' . $input->getArgument('product_id'));
        } else{
          $output->writeln('Updating Image Tags');
        } 
        if ($input->getArgument('product_id')) {
          $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('entity_id', $input->getArgument('product_id'), 'gteq')->create();
          $products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        } else{
          $products = $this->productRepository->getList($this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create());
        }
        if (count($products->getItems()) > 0)  {
            foreach ($products->getItems() as $product) {
                $output->writeln('Updating: ' . $product->getName());
                $title = $product->getName();
                $product = $this->productModel->load($product->getId());
                $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
                if (count($existingMediaGalleryEntries) > 0) {
                    foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
                        $entry->setLabel($title);
                    }
                    $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries)->setStoreId(0)->save();
                }
            }  
        } else {
            $output->writeln('No Products Found');
        }
    }
}
```

> **Console/Command/UpdateAltCmd.php**

This is the logic for our new command and is added within the `Console/Command` directory of the **module** along with the usual module files. The above tells Magento what command initiates the script and then grabs all products. This then loops through each product adding the product name to each of the image alt tags.

### Usage

Once module is installed or remade on your installation run the **command** by using `bin/magento harrigo:updatealt` from Magento root. I have currently only tested this with a handful of products with Magento 2.1.8 however seems to work fine.

**Run from Specific Product ID:**

This command can also be run with a starting **product id** by adding the ID to the end of the `updatealt` command.

**e.g:**

```
bin/magento harrigo:updatealt 100
```

### Download Module

**Example** of this module here: https://github.com/harrigo/ProductUpdateCmd

[image: Screenshot of image update command in action]

### Installation

1. Download Module
2. Place Module Files within `app/code/Harrigo/ProductUpdateCmd` folder from Magento root directory.
3. Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` from Magento root
4. Module is now installed, depending on magento mode you may need to compile and deploy static content etc.

Comment: I used the setLabel and setMediaGalleyEntries section of this answer in M2.4.6 to update the image alt text and it works nicely, but I used product repository to save the product as per 2.4 save practices.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure that this is what you want but I would fix all your current products with an **import**.

From then on in use the below **observer** to make sure the products are saved with your **name** attribute in the **alt** tags.

### Create a Module

Create a new **module** with below code:

### Obeserver Code

```
<?php
namespace Harrigo\ProductUpdate\Observer\Catalog;

class ProductSaveBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

  /**
   * Execute observer
   *
   * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
   * @return void
   */
  public function execute(
      \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
  ) {
      $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // get product object
      //get title
      $title = $_product->getName();
      //get the images
      $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $_product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
      foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
          //set new title for each image
          $entry->setLabel($title);
      }
      //set the new labels for product
      $_product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
  }
}
```

> **Harrigo/ProductUpdate/Observer/Catalog/ProductSaveBefore.php**

### Event

Then set this to run before product save event:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_before">
        <observer instance="Harrigo\ProductUpdate\Observer\Catalog\ProductSaveBefore" name="harrigo_productupdate_observer_catalog_productsavebefore_catalog_product_save_before"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> **Harrigo/ProductUpdate/etc/events.xml**

This was added within `app/code` with all the usual module files. **Harrigo** was the vendor and **ProductUpdate** the module name here.

**Update**

During testing this I have noticed an issue when deleting images for a products with this will post a further update when i get a chance.